# Decode base64 image and save it on a webserver - retrieve the same and encode again

Tags: php, mysql, image, base64

I have an image that I get in the form of a base64 string from an API response. Initially - I was saving the string directly in my database in a `mediumtext` field. But it seems to be eating up too much space.

Is there a way I could save the image as a flat file - store it's link in my image field in the database - and retrieve it using a query again ?

I'm using PHP on the server side - and AWS. I need this as I'm running out of DB space.

Also - I know we could save a base64 string by decoding it to an image and saving it on the server - but how can I retrieve and encode the same?

Comment: Yes, it is very common to store files in the filing system - encoding them in your database makes for slow and cumbersome backups. However, as an interim solution, you could always use database blobs - they are more space efficient than base64 text. Copy your database offline and see what space saving this gets you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this, using pair functions [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)/[base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode):

```
$encoded = 'SomeBase64EncodedString';

$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
// Now $decoded is the binary content of image, save it anywhere you want.
// Example: file_put_content('/tmp/image.png', $decoded);

// When you want to retrieve the base64 encoded string again
$decoded = file_get_contents('/tmp/image.png');
$encoded = base64_encode($decoded);

// Now you have $encoded, as a base64 encoded string. Do as you please with it.
```